# replace 0 into dash in Fast Report

Tags: delphi

Is it Possible to replace 0 value and turn it into dash in fast report?

like:

```
No.   turns to
1         1
2         2
0         -
3         3
0         -
0         -
```

Comment: Please explain why `3` should also turn to `-`. I did not catch the logic behind or it is a typo

Comment: yah its a typo sorry.

Comment: Then please edit the question to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Use a built-in script engine.

Assuming you have a dataset DS and a field FIELD_NAME then instead of `[DS."FIELD_NAME"]` you should write `[IIF(<DS."FIELD_NAME"> = 0, '-',  <DS."FIELD_NAME">)]` as your frxMemoView text.